# Vauxhall Astra 1.6 Sri 2012

Tags: vauxhall, astra, dual-mass-flywheel

Can anyone tell me if my Vauxhall Astra 1.6 Sri 2012 has a DMf? It’s making a rattling noise when driving but then stops when I put the clutch down

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It's a typical symptom of DMF failing. Mine (not Vauxhall) deteriorated progessively. When I took it to a mechanic he listened and said "yes that's the DMF, but this model [DSG transmisson] does not have one!" But it did.

Comment: Which model is your Astra? Hatchback/Estate/GTC/Saloon?